# permanent change via inspect element, ways to make browsers remember my appearance preference?

Tags: css, inspect, preference

Have you seen the smiley jobs guy at the right of the LinkedIn website?

*I want him go away!*

(https://static-exp1.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/promo/ads/li_evergreen_jobs_ad_300x250_v1.jpg)

so, I open inspect element on it, add `display: none;` to its CSS, and there, he's gone...

But when I change pages or refresh it, he comes back, he is very persistent in finding a job for me.

Now, how can I make my browser to remember my appearance preference??

The same goes for the advertisement banners as well,

**How can you teach your browser to not show elements again when you made them disappear by inspect element?**

Comment: That's not possible. If someone harasses you, just report them to the website/app support. If adds bother you ? there are some browser specific addons for that. This is not a question for SO. Good luck

Comment: you did not get the question

Comment: I didn't get your question ? you didn't get the purpose of SO. We are not here to recommend plugins or other stuff like that.

Comment: This is not really the place for such a question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have you seen the smiley jobs guy at the right of the LinkedIn website?

I haven't.

> How can you teach your browser to not show buggers again when you made them disappear by inspect element?

Use [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) if you are using chrome or similar software to automate the process of setting `display: none` on a DOM element. Or more conveniently use some ad-blockers available online.

Comment: I wish I can give another vote up for the "I haven't"

Comment: I wanted to upvote, but haven't got enough points, thanks.

Comment: @LearningMathematics how? will it be closed then? I want to find a way that is self-sufficient and doesn't need external software.

Comment: @MaliheMahdavisefat It won't be closed. You can accept the answer by clicking the tick on the top left corner of the answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @MaliheMahdavisefat You cannot change the code in the server side. That's why you must run your own code in client side in order to achieve your purpose. Tampermonkey is a light weight and common chrome plugin to do that.